# Add Gmail Go-To Actions in Email

Tags: gmail, html-email

Having seen some examples where a custom action is added to the gmail subject line in the inbox, I found [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action) article that details how to construct the buttons. Inspecting a Jira email, you can see this in action:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "EmailMessage",
    "description": "View Issue",
    "potentialAction": {
        "@type": "ViewAction",
            "target": "https://mysite.atlassian.net/browse/B-1111?inbox=true&",
        "name": "View Issue"
        },
    "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Atlassian",
        "url": "https://www.atlassian.com"
    }
}
</script>
```

[image: Custom Action Button in Inbox]

Trying to do this myself, I seem to be running into issues. I'm transmitting this html content:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
            "@context": "http://schema.org",
            "@type": "EmailMessage",
            "description": "Click Me",
            "potentialAction": {
                "@type": "ViewAction",
                "target": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZZ7oFKsKzY",
                "name": "Click Me"        
            },
            "publisher": {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "Bede Gaming",
            "url": "https://www.bedegaming.com"
            }
        }
    </script>

    <p>Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and can see it being transmitted in the received email source:

[image: Gmail Message Content]

The message correctly renders as Html, but for some reason the custom button doesn't appear:

[image: Inbox without the custom button]

Is there something else that needs to be done to make it appear?

Comment: You might need to register your email address with Google
https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google

Comment: Ah, yeah that might be it. I'm only messing about really - I was intrigued to see how it worked. Not sure I want to go through the process of registering since I don't intend to use it in prod (at the moment)

Comment: @Gwesolo That said, the link you posted indicated that emails sent from the same address as the recipient should work. Just tried that and it didn't seem to take either.